# Listing two different custom entity types in one view

Tags: views, 8, entities, database

We defined two entity types, questions and answers. They are related to each other but we will need a view listing all questions and answers in order of title or created date for example. When you build a view you have to choose one entity type which will be listed in a row maybe including the data from referenced entities but you do not get a view listing the base entity and the referenced entities each in a seperate row. Additionally the view we need should not depend on this reference - each entity should be filtered and sorted individually. I think I need someting like UNION in SQL?! Is there a way to achieve this with core Views module?

Comment: Core views can show different bundles of the same entity (e.g. different content types when showing nodes), because they share the same base tables in SQL ==> It is basically the same query with different where-clause. But this is also the reason why Views module will not be able to create a SQL union-like view accross different entity types, they have different base tables. You can join tables/entities (see Relationships under Advanced in Views UI), but no union.

Comment: Thank you... I think the idea of defining bundles instead of different entity types may already be a good idea as these entity types have many base fields in common...